# Detect failure in network request and sync data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, httprequest

I have a web application whose front end is powered by angular.js and back end nodejs (hapi.js).
In a function my application talks to `Server A` and return a bool value, if its a success then it talks to `Server B` and update a field in the DB. 
It works fine but during a network failure the `Server A` gets updated but `Server B` is in old state , when i check the network panel in browser the request to `Server A` is pending for a long time when i refresh it the `Server A` is updated but not `Server B`

Can anyone suggest a good way to sync